# Adding placeholder text in voucher code input Prestashop

Tags: text, prestashop-1.6, placeholder, inputbox

I have some difficulty to add a placeholder text in my voucher input box.

The page can be found at the following link:
[Order Page](https://www.backlabel.com/ordine)

The website is built with Prestashop 1.6.17.

I would like to add 'Enter voucher code here' to the white input box below the image, [as shown in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrrs3.jpg)

I added a string - placeholder text-  in the html with chrome inspect function:

```
<input type="text" class="discount_name form-control" id="discount_name" name="discount_name" value="" placeholder="insert voucher code here">
```

However I do not know where to modify in Prestashop as there a no such html pages to look for. Does anyone have an idea?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit `themes/your_theme/shopping-cart.tpl` and edit the voucher input.
Make sure you clear cache afterwards if you have it enabled.

[Here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/shopping-cart.tpl#L132) is the default theme's voucher input. There is one than more input depending on your tax and price settings in the default theme.

Your theme may be different but it should be in the same file.

Comment: @franfran00 Then accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it (I'm new) - I have now accepted it! Thank you again!